# Convert drupal 7 content type into code automatically. Content type generator code?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-content-types

I already have a content type in my drupal project.

I am currently working on my own module and would like to create a built in content type.
Is there a way to convert a content type that I built directly in drupal into code ?
A kind of Content Type Code Generator ?.

I want to generate this code automatically if it's possible.

```
$t = get_t();

  // Define the node type.
  $slider = array(
    'type' => 'slider',
    'name' => $t('Slider Content'),
    'base' => 'node_content',
    'description' => $t('This is an example node type with a few fields.'),
    'body_label' => $t('Example Description')
  );

  // Complete the node type definition by setting any defaults not explicitly
  // declared above.
  // http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_type_set_defaults/7
  $content_type = node_type_set_defaults($slider);
  node_add_body_field($content_type);

  // Save the content type
  node_type_save($content_type);
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at [Features module](https://drupal.org/project/features). Using Features should allow you to export your content type along with added fields into a module you can install to another site later.

Check [this documentation link](https://drupal.org/node/580052).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you.

add hook_install():

please check: http://yaremchuk.ru/blog/how-create-content-type-drupal-7-programmatically

Comment: I already seen this link and that's nothing about what I'm trying to do. I want something to generate automatically the code for content type. Thanks.